# How to create an index in a nested MongoDB collection?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, geojson

I have a MongoDB collection which includes people and two sets of contact details with GeoJSON coordinates - office and home. In this collection, I would like to add a 2dsphere index on these coordinate fields so I could create a function that finds the nearest office to where the user is.

My collection (minified a bit to remove some sensitive data) looks like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("61a64ce6c7c66e3e3ca71ea3"),
        "MemberName" : "Somename",
        "MemberLastName" : "name",
        "MemberFirstName" : "Some",
        "Province" : "SomeProvince",
        "MemberPrefix" : "Ms",
        "ContactDetails" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("61a64ce7c7c66e3e3ca7235d"),
                        "MemberName" : "SomeName",
                        "AddressType" : "Office",
                        "Address1" : "TestTown",
                        "Townland" : "TestTown",
                        "TownCity" : "Testtesttestlol",
                        "Postcode" : "TTT 4TT",
                        "Location" : {
                                "type" : "Point",
                                "coordinates" : [
                                        -5.872474572689,
                                        54.578308571336
                                ]
                        }
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("61a64ce7c7c66e3e3ca7235e"),
                        "MemberName" : "SomeName",
                        "AddressType" : "Home",
                        "Address1" : "HomeAddress",
                        "Townland" : "TestTown",
                        "TownCity" : "TownTest",
                        "Postcode" : "TT5 H55",
                        "Location" : {
                                "type" : "Point",
                                "coordinates" : [
                                        -5.828601611087,
                                        54.59907579121
                                ]
                        }
                }
        ],
```

The question I have is how can I add a 2dsphere index to each member's office location? So far, with PyMongo I've used:

```
members.create_index([("ContactDetails.Location", pymongo.GEOSPHERE)])
```

Which reports that the index for this field was successfully created. However, when I attempt to actually use this to retrieve data, nothing is output from the console. Is my key fine or is it an issue with the test script I've made?

geotest.py:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017")
db = client.memberDB
members = db.members


for neighbour in members.aggregate( [
 { "$geoNear" :
 { "near" :
 { "type" : "Point",
 "coordinates" :
 [54.89398396718853, -6.045212206625715] },
 "maxDistance": 50000,
 "minDistance" : 1,
 "distanceField" : "distance",
 "spherical" : True
 }
 }
 ]):
    print(neighbour)
```

**EDIT:**
As requested by R2D2, this is the output from the above query when .explain() is used in the shell:

```json
{
        "explainVersion" : "1",
        "stages" : [
                {
                        "$geoNearCursor" : {
                                "queryPlanner" : {
                                        "namespace" : "memberDB.members",
                                        "indexFilterSet" : false,
                                        "parsedQuery" : {
                                                "ContactDetails.Location" : {
                                                        "$nearSphere" : {
                                                                "type" : "Point",
                                                                "coordinates" : [
                                                                        54.88053164695987,
                                                                        -6.458416339402716
                                                                ]
                                                        },
                                                        "$minDistance" : 1,
                                                        "$maxDistance" : 5000000
                                                }
                                        },
                                        "queryHash" : "003B7873",
                                        "planCacheKey" : "13FEDF92",
                                        "maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached" : false,
                                        "maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached" : false,
                                        "maxScansToExplodeReached" : false,
                                        "winningPlan" : {
                                                "stage" : "GEO_NEAR_2DSPHERE",
                                                "keyPattern" : {
                                                        "ContactDetails.Location" : "2dsphere"
                                                },
                                                "indexName" : "ContactDetails.Location_2dsphere",
                                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                                "inputStage" : {
                                                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                                "keyPattern" : {
                                                                        "ContactDetails.Location" : "2dsphere"
                                                                },
                                                                "indexName" : "ContactDetails.Location_2dsphere",
                                                                "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                                        "ContactDetails.Location" : [
                                                                                "ContactDetails"
                                                                        ]
                                                                },
                                                                "isUnique" : false,
                                                                "isSparse" : false,
                                                                "isPartial" : false,
                                                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                                                "direction" : "forward",
                                                                "indexBounds" : {
                                                                        "ContactDetails.Location" : [
                                                                                "[-5620492334958379007, -5476377146882523137]",
                                                                                "[-5476377146882523135, -5332261958806667265]",
                                                                                "[1152921504606846977, 1297036692682702847]",
                                                                                "[1369094286720630784, 1369094286720630784]",
                                                                                "[1423137482249076736, 1423137482249076736]",
                                                                                "[1432144681503817729, 1441151880758558719]",
                                                                                "[1441151880758558721, 1585267068834414591]",
                                                                                "[1585267068834414593, 1729382256910270463]",
                                                                                "[1729382256910270465, 2305843009213693951]",
                                                                                "[2305843009213693953, 2882303761517117439]",
                                                                                "[2882303761517117441, 3026418949592973311]",
                                                                                "[3386706919782612992, 3386706919782612992]",
                                                                                "[3386706919782612993, 3422735716801576959]",
                                                                                "[3422735716801576961, 3458764513820540927]",
                                                                                "[3458764513820540929, 3602879701896396799]",
                                                                                "[4035225266123964417, 4611686018427387903]",
                                                                                "[4611686018427387905, 4647714815446351871]",
                                                                                "[4683743612465315840, 4683743612465315840]"
                                                                        ]
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        },
                                        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                                },
                                "executionStats" : {
                                        "executionSuccess" : true,
                                        "nReturned" : 0,
                                        "executionTimeMillis" : 1,
                                        "totalKeysExamined" : 1,
                                        "totalDocsExamined" : 0,
                                        "executionStages" : {
                                                "stage" : "GEO_NEAR_2DSPHERE",
                                                "nReturned" : 0,
                                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                                                "works" : 27,
                                                "advanced" : 0,
                                                "needTime" : 26,
                                                "needYield" : 0,
                                                "saveState" : 1,
                                                "restoreState" : 1,
                                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                                "keyPattern" : {
                                                        "ContactDetails.Location" : "2dsphere"
                                                },
                                                "indexName" : "ContactDetails.Location_2dsphere",
                                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                                "searchIntervals" : [
                                                        {
                                                                "minDistance" : 1,
                                                                "maxDistance" : 5000000,
                                                                "maxInclusive" : true,
                                                                "nBuffered" : 0,
                                                                "nReturned" : 0
                                                        }
                                                ],
                                                "inputStage" : {
                                                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                                                        "nReturned" : 0,
                                                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                                                        "works" : 1,
                                                        "advanced" : 0,
                                                        "needTime" : 0,
                                                        "needYield" : 0,
                                                        "saveState" : 0,
                                                        "restoreState" : 0,
                                                        "isEOF" : 1,
                                                        "docsExamined" : 0,
                                                        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                                "nReturned" : 0,
                                                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                                                                "works" : 1,
                                                                "advanced" : 0,
                                                                "needTime" : 0,
                                                                "needYield" : 0,
                                                                "saveState" : 0,
                                                                "restoreState" : 0,
                                                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                                                "keyPattern" : {
                                                                        "ContactDetails.Location" : "2dsphere"
                                                                },
                                                                "indexName" : "ContactDetails.Location_2dsphere",
                                                                "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                                        "ContactDetails.Location" : [
                                                                                "ContactDetails"
                                                                        ]
                                                                },
                                                                "isUnique" : false,
                                                                "isSparse" : false,
                                                                "isPartial" : false,
                                                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                                                "direction" : "forward",
                                                                "indexBounds" : {
                                                                        "ContactDetails.Location" : [
                                                                                "[-5620492334958379007, -5476377146882523137]",
                                                                                "[-5476377146882523135, -5332261958806667265]",
                                                                                "[1152921504606846977, 1297036692682702847]",
                                                                                "[1369094286720630784, 1369094286720630784]",
                                                                                "[1423137482249076736, 1423137482249076736]",
                                                                                "[1432144681503817729, 1441151880758558719]",
                                                                                "[1441151880758558721, 1585267068834414591]",
                                                                                "[1585267068834414593, 1729382256910270463]",
                                                                                "[1729382256910270465, 2305843009213693951]",
                                                                                "[2305843009213693953, 2882303761517117439]",
                                                                                "[2882303761517117441, 3026418949592973311]",
                                                                                "[3386706919782612992, 3386706919782612992]",
                                                                                "[3386706919782612993, 3422735716801576959]",
                                                                                "[3422735716801576961, 3458764513820540927]",
                                                                                "[3458764513820540929, 3602879701896396799]",
                                                                                "[4035225266123964417, 4611686018427387903]",
                                                                                "[4611686018427387905, 4647714815446351871]",
                                                                                "[4683743612465315840, 4683743612465315840]"
                                                                        ]
                                                                },
                                                                "keysExamined" : 1,
                                                                "seeks" : 1,
                                                                "dupsTested" : 0,
                                                                "dupsDropped" : 0
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        },
                                        "allPlansExecution" : [ ]
                                }
                        },
                        "nReturned" : NumberLong(0),
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        ],
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "Orthanc",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "5.0.3",
                "gitVersion" : "657fea5a61a74d7a79df7aff8e4bcf0bc742b748"
        },
        "serverParameters" : {
                "internalQueryFacetBufferSizeBytes" : 104857600,
                "internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes" : 104857600,
                "internalLookupStageIntermediateDocumentMaxSizeBytes" : 104857600,
                "internalDocumentSourceGroupMaxMemoryBytes" : 104857600,
                "internalQueryMaxBlockingSortMemoryUsageBytes" : 104857600,
                "internalQueryProhibitBlockingMergeOnMongoS" : 0,
                "internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes" : 104857600,
                "internalDocumentSourceSetWindowFieldsMaxMemoryBytes" : 104857600
        },
        "command" : {
                "aggregate" : "members",
                "pipeline" : [
                        {
                                "$geoNear" : {
                                        "near" : {
                                                "type" : "Point",
                                                "coordinates" : [
                                                        54.88053164695987,
                                                        -6.458416339402716
                                                ]
                                        },
                                        "maxDistance" : 5000000,
                                        "minDistance" : 1,
                                        "distanceField" : "distance",
                                        "spherical" : "true"
                                }
                        }
                ],
                "cursor" : {

                },
                "$db" : "memberDB"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have typo in the code, you need to create the index on:

```
"ContactDetails.location"
```

instead of:

```
"ContactDetails.Location"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! That is my bad, that was a transcription error when I was typing this post. It is actually `Location` in the database too, I've fixed the original question to reflect this. The issue is still there for the code. Thanks for pointing that out though!

Comment: Can you post output from members.explain(true).aggregate() so we can see how mongo interpret your query?

Comment: Certainly, I have updated the original post with the output.

Comment: It looks like you have long/lat reversed in the query.  The points [-5, 54]  and [54,-5] are both valid points, but they are 8500km apart.